# Fullcalendar. Saving external-events after event is first dragged-dropped onto calendar

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar

I am planning on using the EXCELLENT FullCalendar JQUERY plugin https://fullcalendar.io/  as a core part of an operational system. At the moment I am prototyping to check whether the plug in will do the job. I am very nearly finished and have found just one issue that I can find no solution for anywhere on the internet or in the documentation.

Key to understanding my problem is that I need to use the external-events configuration (code as below) of FullCalendar. So...when I drag an element *already on the calendar* between dates it triggers the eventdDrop event and my alert message returns the event data of the event object- all exactly as expected. So I know I can easily replace the alert with an AJAX Post to register the new (moved) event data in the database.

However my problem.... When I now drag one of the external-events (eg GAS Cert due) onto the calendar it does not trigger the eventdrop event when it first gets dropped on the calendar. So I am struggling to figure out how I can save event data (from a dragged external-event) into the database - when the event is first dropped on the calendar by dragging it from the external-event list. (For info:-if i subsequently move the new event created to a new calendar date, eventDrop *is* triggered. However oftentimes the user will simply drag external-events onto the calendar and leave them there for days or weeks - during that period the event data on the calendar needs saving to the database for subsequent page re-visits.

I have been searching for ages with no luck. Thanks if anyone has a neat solution.

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <head>
                <meta charset='utf-8' />
                <link href='../fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
                <link href='../fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
                <script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
                <script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
                <script src='../lib/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
                <script src='../fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
                <script>

                    $(document).ready(function() {

                        /* initialize the external events
                        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

                        $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

                            // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
                            $(this).data('event', {
                                title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                                stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                            });

                            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                            $(this).draggable({
                                zIndex: 999,
                                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                            });

                        });


                        /* initialize the calendar
                        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                            header: {
                                left: 'prev,next today',
                                center: 'title',
                                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                            },


                            editable: true,
                            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar

                        /*-------Problem------Event is triggered when object is moved on calendar-but not when event is dragged and dropped from external events list-help?----------------------------------*/ 
                            eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
                            //inner column movement drop so get start and call the ajax function......
                            console.log(event.start.format());
                            console.log(event.id);
                            var defaultDuration = moment.duration($('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'defaultTimedEventDuration')); // get the default and convert it to proper type
                            var end = event.end || event.start.clone().add(defaultDuration); // If there is no end, compute it
                            console.log('end is ' + end.format());

                            alert(event.title + " was dropped on " + event.start.format()); //REPLACE WITH AJAX TO SAVE EVENT DATA

                        },

                            drop: function() {
                                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                                    $(this).remove();
                                }
                            },                  


                            events: [
                                {
                                    title: 'All Day Event',
                                    start: '2017-02-01'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Long Event',
                                    start: '2017-02-07',
                                    end: '2017-02-10'
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 999,
                                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                                    start: '2017-02-09T16:00:00'
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 999,
                                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                                    start: '2017-02-16T16:00:00'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Conference',
                                    start: '2017-02-11',
                                    end: '2017-02-13'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Meeting',
                                    start: '2017-02-12T10:30:00',
                                    end: '2017-02-12T12:30:00'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Lunch',
                                    start: '2017-02-12T12:00:00'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Meeting',
                                    start: '2017-02-12T14:30:00'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Happy Hour',
                                    start: '2017-02-12T17:30:00'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Dinner',
                                    start: '2017-02-12T20:00:00'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                                    start: '2017-02-13T07:00:00'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Click for Google',
                                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                                    start: '2017-02-28'
                                }
                            ]

                        });


                    });

                </script>
                <style>

                    body {
                        margin-top: 40px;
                        text-align: center;
                        font-size: 14px;
                        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
                    }

                    #wrap {
                        width: 1100px;
                        margin: 0 auto;
                    }

                    #external-events {
                        float: left;
                        width: 150px;
                        padding: 0 10px;
                        border: 1px solid #ccc;
                        background: #eee;
                        text-align: left;
                    }

                    #external-events h4 {
                        font-size: 16px;
                        margin-top: 0;
                        padding-top: 1em;
                    }

                    #external-events .fc-event {
                        margin: 10px 0;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }

                    #external-events p {
                        margin: 1.5em 0;
                        font-size: 11px;
                        color: #666;
                    }

                    #external-events p input {
                        margin: 0;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                    }

                    #calendar {
                        float: right;
                        width: 900px;
                    }

                </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id='wrap'>

                        <div id='external-events'>
                            <h4>Draggable Events</h4>
                            <div class='fc-event' style="color:red">Gas Cert Due Today</div>
                            <div class='fc-event'>Electricity Cert is Due</div>
                            <div class='fc-event'></div>
                            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
                            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
                            <p>
                                <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' />
                                <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <div id='calendar'></div>

                        <div style='clear:both'></div>

                    </div>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that this is the wrong callback, in the documentation it says that: *eventDrop does not get called when an external event lands on the calendar. `eventReceive` is called instead.*

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/

So you have to use `eventReceive`

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/eventReceive/

Comment: Ahhh OK thank you. I haven't used this plug in before. Is there anything specific i need to the eventRecieve arguments to get the start date, end date and title data ready for posting?

Comment: I did try to mark up your answer. My reputation is not high enough it seems to do that. But genuine thanks for your help

Comment: I am really sorry....but where do i actually accept your answer. More than happy to add it as accepted.

Comment: I think by clicking the checkmark below the voting arrows, i'm glad to help

Comment: Yes it was. Not altogether obvious. I have accepted it now. Thank you